# How to filter browser resolution by size and/or device in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to know what is the **greatest horizontal browser resolution** that can support the **majority** of our web traffic.

Google Analytics is only capable of showing a breakdown by unique browser resolutions, this means I have to parse through over 400 unique resolutions. Is there a way filter these resolutions by a specified greater or less than horizontal width?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in the WebUI, what you'll have to do is either use Google Data Studio and create a calculated field based on the resolution dimension OR import the data into Excel/Google Sheets and manipulate it there.